# How to get MariaDB (MySql) query time?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, tuning

I'm using MariaDB 10.1. How to get actual query time for all of executed query? It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time#answer-32643345) that `SHOW PROFILES;` was deprecated. Is there a better solution for database tuning?

**Edit:** It's deprecated only in MySQL 5.6.7.

Comment: i just checked `SHOW PROFILES` is still present in 10.1.18

Comment: @jerichorivera that's true. I'm wrong. It's [deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profiles.html) only in MySQL 5.6.7. Is there a way to get time of _all_ executed queries (using various drivers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `long_query_time=0` and turn on the slowlog to a `FILE` (in `my.cnf`, and restart).  Then the slowlog will contain a variety of info about every command executed, including the query time.

You might also want to run `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slow log.  This will include min/max/avg/etc for each 'different' query.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks. Is there any performance issues with enabling `slow_query_log`?

Comment: The performance impact is pretty small -- one append to file per query.  However, in a busy system this could fill up the disk pretty fast.  So keep an eye on disk space.  You might do this for a day or week, then set `long_query_time = 1` do save disk space while catching only the really naughty queries.